# Using custom linker script with Go build

Tags: go, go-toolchain

Is it possible to use custom linker script (.ldscript) as the Go executable generated from `go build` command is not supported on my target environment as it expects the sections to be in different order ?

I checked the `go tool link` -extld option, but this expects the linker path and not script if I'm correct.

Comment: Interesting. What env are you using?

Comment: @advayrajhansa, I don't think ```go env``` has anything to do with my query on using custom linker script.

Comment: Agreed. I was just wondering what env needs a custom linking script.

Comment: @advayrajhansa, loader on the target environment expects the executable sections in a specific order which is different than default go executable order. That's the reason I want to use a linker script.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for future reference.

It is possible to link custom linker scripts using

`go build -ldflags="-linkmode=external -extldflags=-T<linker-script>`

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to use custom linker script (.ldscript) [?]

No.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See answer from 0xFFFFFFF0.